# cgo CFLAGS not working when include openssl

Tags: openssl, mingw, cgo

I'm trying to call some C++ function in go and these function used the openssl library. However, it seems like that the "CFLAGS" not working.

I have declared the include path by the following code:

```
//#cgo CFLAGS: -IC:/Programs/mingw64/opt/include
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -LC:/Programs/mingw64/opt/lib -lcrypto
//#include "gt.h"
```

But when I run `go run .`, it ouputs:

```
# gt
gt.cpp:3:10: fatal error: openssl/bn.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/bn.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Additionally, when I run `go tool cgo main.go`, I found no flags in `my_project/_obj/_cgo_flags`. The content of this file are below.

```
_CGO_CFLAGS=
```

How can I check my include path? How to fix this problem?

Files in my project folder:

```
// main.go

package main

//#cgo CFLAGS: -IC:/Programs/mingw64/opt/include
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -LC:/Programs/mingw64/opt/lib -lcrypto
//#include "gt.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.foo()
}
```

```
// gt.cpp

#include "gt.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

using namespace std;

void foo() {
    BN_CTX* ctx = BN_CTX_new();
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

```
// gt.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

My Enviroment:

```
OS:
Windows 10

Go version:
go version go1.15.2 windows/amd64

mingw:
I am not very sure. I have install mingw64 and git. So I have 2 mingw.
One was located at "C:\Programs\mingw64", the other "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64".

gcc -v:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Programs/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)


g++ -v:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Programs/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

go tool cgo -V:
cgo version go1.15.2
```

Comment: I change `#cgo CFLAGS` to `#cgo CXXFLAGS` and it compiles. But the foo function doesn't work.

Comment: Finally I copy the "libeay32.dll" to my project folder and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Controls C resources **CFLAGS**.
These parameters are sent to **GCC**. No **G++**.

Go has the ability to compile CPP files. But you have to set these parameters yourself.
Here is the parameter name: `CXXFLAGS`
The parameters you set here will be sent to **G++**.

In addition, in projects you together with C and CPP, the **".h"** extension may cause you many mistakes.
I think it would be better to make the extension of C ++ files **".hpp"**.

I did not use OpenSSL. If it can be compiled statically, you can get rid of DLL files. (License and other things can be important.) :-)
Like this:

```
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -LC:/Programs/mingw64/opt/lib crypto.a otherlibs.a
```

The second parameter does not have `-l`. This is important.